# Trigger select from deleted.. find who deleted?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a Trigger and I was wondering on if there is a way to find out who did the deletion of the record?

When I use SUSER_NAME() in the trigger or the USER_NAME() or even USER I am only getting the SQL login id.  The trigger is being activated from another software that has .net backend that we can customize.

```
USE JM_SB
GO

ALTER TRIGGER Sales_Update
ON Sales
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @Action VARCHAR(30)
   DECLARE @UNAME VARCHAR(30)

   IF UPDATE(PartGroupID)
   BEGIN
          SET @Action = 'Updated Part Group'

          /* All this does is get dbo */
            Set @UNAME = (Select USER From Deleted)  

            INSERT INTO Sales_AuditTrail(Action, SalesID, OldValue, 
            NewValue, SalesDivision, UpdateDate, UpdatedUser)
            SELECT @Action, i.SalesID, d.PartGroupID, i.PartGroupID, 
            i.SalesDivision, Current_Timestamp As UpdateDate, @UNAME
            FROM Inserted i
            INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.SalesID = d.SalesID

   END  
END;
GO
```

Does the table deleted or inserted know the person who updated the record? Instead of dbo or sa ... from the software that triggers the update my username for ex: "jmadmin"

Comment: I doubt it.  The database is going to track who is logged into the database.  The software system itself might be keeping track of individual users.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be a long shot. Was hoping that maybe lol

Comment: Also, this may not do quite what you think it will. the UPDATE function evaluates to true if the column is part of the udpate statement. It does NOT evaluate if the inserted and deleted values are different. I would probably skip the UPDATE function and include i.PartGroupID <> d.PartGroupID as a where predicate for the insert.

Comment: Correct.  The trigger will only ever know the SQL login.  If you need the application login (and it's different than the SQL login) then the application will need to send it in the SQL statement(s).

Comment: I just realized you are asking about who deleted the row but this trigger is an UPDATE trigger. >.<

Comment: If the software has the context of the end user and you can customize it, you could store use CONTEXT_INFO pre-SQL 2016 or SESSION_CONTEXT() in SQL 2016 and later to store the user's identity for use in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used and it works. Thanks everyone.

```
   DECLARE @cUserID As varchar(35)

   SET @cUserID = Upper(Left(App_Name(),20))
```